# Inconsistent Stored Procedure Calls from One PC to Another

Tags: ms-access, vba, oledb, ado

I have an unbound Access form that populates a text box with data retrieved from SQL Server 2008 via a stored procedure `GetIssueComponents()`. Below is the code for this. The code works. My problem is that some PCs will consistently execute the function calls and retrieve the data all within a second. However, other computers will take tens of seconds to do this. We even have one machine that takes a full minute or two! Every machine is different on how long they take, but each one is consistent with the timing.

It doesn't seem to be anything directly related to hardware as many of the computers are identical configurations, and in fact the worst computer we have is one of the very fastest at executing the procedure! The ODBC drivers are identical on all the computers as well. All the computers are running Windows XP and I believe they all have the same patches installed. I don't know where else to look, please help!

```
Global adoCnn As New ADODB.Connection

Public Function ADO_ConnectionInitialize() As Boolean
Const DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME = "ADO_ConnectionInitialize"
Debug_Proc_Start DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME, True
On Error GoTo ADO_ConnectionInitialize_Error

    ADO_ConnectionInitialize = False
    If adoCnn.state = adStateClosed Then
        adoCnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=10.10.10.10;Initial Catalog=" & DATABASE_NAME & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        adoCnn.Open
    End If
    ADO_ConnectionInitialize = True

ADO_ConnectionInitialize_Error:
Select Case Debug_Proc_End(DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME, True)
    Case vbAbort
        Debug.Assert False
        Resume
    Case vbRetry
        Resume
    Case vbIgnore
        Resume Next
    Case vbCancel
    Case vbOK
    Case Else
End Select
End Function

Public Function ADO_StoredProcedure(ProcName As String, Optional parameters As Variant) As ADODB.parameters

    Dim comm As ADODB.Command
    Dim p As Variant
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter

    If ADO_ConnectionInitialize() Then
        Set comm = New ADODB.Command
        With comm
            .ActiveConnection = adoCnn
            .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
            .CommandText = ProcName
            For Each p In parameters
                If IsNull(p(3)) Then
                    Set param = .CreateParameter(p(0), p(1), p(2))
                Else
                    Set param = .CreateParameter(p(0), p(1), p(2), p(3))
                End If
                .parameters.Append param
                If p(2) = adParamInput Or p(2) = adParamInputOutput Then
                    .parameters(p(0)).value = p(4)
                End If
            Next
        End With
        comm.Execute
        Set ADO_StoredProcedure = comm.parameters
        Set comm = Nothing 'Memory leak if this isn't done??
    End If

    End Function


    Public Function GetIssueComponents(ByVal issueID As Long) As String
    Const DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME = "GetIssueComponents"
    Debug_Proc_Start DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME
    On Error GoTo GetIssueComponents_Error

        Dim params As ADODB.parameters
        Dim p As ADODB.Parameter

        Set params = ADO_StoredProcedure("dbo.GetIssueComponents", Array( _
            Array("@ReturnValue", _
                ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, _
                ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamReturnValue, _
                Null, _
                Null), _
            Array("@issueID", _
                ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adInteger, _
                ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, _
                Null, _
                issueID), _
            Array("@Components", _
                ADODB.DataTypeEnum.adVarChar, _
                ADODB.ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamOutput, _
                255, _
                Null) _
        ))
        GetIssueComponents = params("@components").value

    GetIssueComponents_Error:
    Select Case Debug_Proc_End(DEBUG_THIS_PROC_NAME)
        Case vbAbort
            Debug.Assert False
            Resume
        Case vbRetry
            Resume
        Case vbIgnore
            Resume Next
        Case vbCancel
        Case vbOK
        Case Else
    End Select
    End Function
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. I would recommend setting short timeouts on your connection and/or command objects to see if the timeouts are tripped. You should probably try using SQL Server Profiler to see if there's any locks showing up in there. What happens if you reboot your server or the SQL Services on the server? Are all of the machines just as slow the first time they run the SP?

Comment: The server has been restarted a few different times (for other reasons) and all the PCs involved have had their own reboots quite regularly. This has been going on ever since I implemented the code over a month ago, so it doesn't seem to be fleeting. On the server, I have done tests with just one PC active at any time, and all machines maintain their individual characteristic slow or fast procedure times.

Comment: Have you set a break point and stepped through the code line by line to pinpoint which step is the bottleneck on the slow machines?

Comment: In the procedure `ADO_StoredProcedure` on the line `comm.Execute` is where it hangs. The connection is a OLE DB, I accidently tagged it with ODBC... will fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an answer as to *why* the connection performs differently from one pc to the next, but I did find that changing form OLE DB to ODBC completely eliminates the problem. My new connection string is as follows:

```
adoCnn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER=sql server;SERVER=" & DATABASE_IP & ";APP=Microsoft Office 2010;DATABASE=" & DATABASE_NAME & ";Network=DBMSSOCN;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

So this counts as a work around, but I would still love to hear details about OLE DB and why it performs so inconsistently.